# Changing OutputCache based on URL

Tags: asp.net, caching, url-rewriting

I have got page which I would like to cache using the OutputCache directive. However, I am using a URL rewriter module to direct multiple URLs at this page, each with different contents.

Is there any way to use the cache the output for each URL? There are no other criteria by which I need to vary the cache results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the end this was quite simple to fix.

1. Add the following directive to the page that needs to be cached:

   < %@ outputcache duration="600" location="Downstream" varybyparam="none" varybycustom="RawURL" %>
2. Add this method to the global.asax file

   ```
   public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
   {
       switch (custom.ToUpper())
       {
           case "RAWURL":
               return context.Request.RawUrl;

           default:
               return "";
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is clever... but it's still returning a 200 instead of a 304 (Not Modified) as it would with a non-routed URL.  So although it may not be *generating* the page again, the client still has to *get* it again, rather than using its local cache.  Still, good question.

Answer (score 0):

Programatically you can set Caching options using **Response.Cache**. You can switch on your querystring variable and depending on the case, set properties on **Response.Cache** appropriately.

[MSDN on Cache object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cache%28VS.71%29.aspx)
[Another helpful article from aspalliance.com](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webapps/settingoutputcachelocation.aspx)

Comment: I can also vary the cache based on the request headers, but these do not change and there are no querystring variables used